# Intellij regex String replace a new instance of a class declaration with a method param

Tags: java, regex, string, intellij-idea

Here's a function

```
public Car returnCar(){
    return new Car();
}
```

I need to transform it to

```
public Car returnCar(Car car){
    return car;
}
```

There are similar methods in multiple class return different types.

Is there a way to leverage regex **global** search/replace across files in Intellij to do this without writing an external utility?

Answer (score 1):

Select `new Car()`, extract it as a parameter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for me, or find it in the refactoring menu).